# how to use a single modal for displaying multiple images

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

as per the database table rows. My page will be populated with multiple rows(currently 32) Each row has an image. I have created a button/link at the nd of each row. I need a popup (#modal) displaying the image fetching from database. as the button is clicked.

I want a particular image fetched from the database table using id passed(id given when clicked link) 
and displayed under the image tag in popup.
Any way out? I have my code below  I NEED to use ONE modal for displaying various images; fetching on time?? I am confused over it. but i know there is way out.
I am sorry if I am not clear.

```html
// there will be many links depending on the no. of rows in database
      <a href="#checkImage" data-toggle="modal">  Image </a>





<div class="modal fade" id="checkImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;" id="myModalLabel">Reset Password</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;">
        
        <h1>Your Image</h1>
        
        <img src=#fetchedImageFromDB>
        
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pass the image src to modal on clicking of the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another [data attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)  to your anchor.

```
<a href="#checkImage" data-toggle="modal" data-myimage="imageurl.jpg">  Image </a>
```

Then, in your modal, get the "myimage" (not use Uppercase character to avoid compatibility issues) value and put it inside your modal.
Your Javascript library should help you.

It should work...

Comment: hello perpaolo. Can you please tell me how in my modal. I can  get the value of myimage? will be great help

Comment: @newUser Are you using pure javascript ore some kind of library (e.g. jQuery)?

Comment: hello @pierpaolo. Thanks for replying back. Using your answer. I managed to get somewhere and rest of the problem was answered here. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165190/how-to-pass-data-attribute-in-modal/33165981#33165981

Comment: @newUser congratulation: I think a solution found by your searches is more satisfying :)