# how to pass data-attribute in modal

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I need to pass the data attribute in my modal. to attach with image tag in src When clicked on the link. Below is my code. I am confused. I know we can use JavaScript onclick method to pass by reference. Still can anyone give me executable code. My code is below. I am not really good in making JavaScript functions.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<a href="#checkImage" data-toggle="modal" data-myimage="imageNamefromDataBase.jpg">  Image </a>
<div class="modal fade" id="checkImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;" id="myModalLabel">View Image</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;">
        <h1>Fee Submit</h1>
        <img src="#" alt="bank_chalan" id="thanks" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">       
       <button type='submit' data-dismiss="modal" name='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this Official Demo https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-related-target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include image(s) into bootstrap modal, try something like this.

```
<a id = 'checkImage' >Image</a>
<div id = 'imagemodal' class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View Image</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h1>Fee Submit</h1>
        <img src="http://www.userlogos.org/files/logos/Karmody/alaTest_Iphone01a.png" id="imagepreview" >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

In you JS file, add this

```
$(function() {
    $('#checkImage').on('click', function() {
        $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use bootstrap modal [event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) listener `show` or `shown` and pass the data attribute value to `<img>`

```
$('#checkImage').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var img = $(e.relatedTarget).data('myimage');
    //alert(img);
    $("#thanks").attr("src",img);
});
```

Working Example

```js
 $('#checkImage').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
     var img = $(e.relatedTarget).data('myimage');
     //alert(img);
     $("#thanks").attr("src", img);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<a href="#checkImage" data-toggle="modal" data-myimage="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/images/1.png" class="btn btn-default">  Image </a>

<div class="modal fade" id="checkImage" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;" id="myModalLabel">View Image</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;">
                 <h1>Fee Submit</h1>

                <img src="#" alt="bank_chalan" id="thanks" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type='submit' data-dismiss="modal" name='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g2msesjo/1/)

[Multiple Images](http://jsfiddle.net/g2msesjo/5/)